# Can't use a gesture LongPress in Flutter App

Tags: java, appium-java, appium-flutter

I am trying to automate a Flutter Mobile app with Appium. In the application there is a transaction flow where i need to press and hold a button to execute the transaction. I tried to use touchAction function, it didn't work. I also use W3c protocol to perform the gesture but it didn't work as well. I am trying to find the solution for 2days but got no luck. Could you please help?

I am attaching a Screenshot of my Code snippet.

--- This is the method
[Method for longpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnRZw.png)

--- --- This is where i call the method
[call the method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JFOE.png)

Stackrace: [Stackrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1eab.png)